# Can `strings.split` ignore empty tokens?

Tags: go

Can you please demonstrate an efficient way to use `strings.split` such that empty tokens are not included in the returned slice?

Specifically, the following code returns `["a" "" "b" "c"]` where I want to have it return `["a" "b" "c"]`:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", strings.Split("a,,b,c", ","))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/keaSjjSxgn

Comment: Implement an additional function that would filter out the elements you don't want to be there. Effectively it would be a loop that iterates over string and checks their length is greater than 0. Due to lack of generics - Go cannot have a library function that does exactly that for you, so have fun re-implementing it over and over again :-)

Comment: Actually, if you need to do this a lot with different slice types take a look at how the `sort` package works, no generics needed. However, for just string slices writing a generic solution is way overkill.

Comment: @MiloChristiansen `func Sort(data Interface)` --- that's how it works, using interfaces. So you must implement the interface for every data type, over and over again.

Comment: Exactly. `sort.Slice` is closer to this problem though, and IIRC it uses reflection.

Comment: "IIRC it uses reflection" --- yikes :-D

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Short answer: `strings.Split` can't do that.

However, there are more functions to split strings in Go. Notably, you can do what you want with [`strings.FieldsFunc`](https://godoc.org/strings#FieldsFunc). The example here:

```
splitFn := func(c rune) bool {
        return c == ','
}
fmt.Printf("Fields are: %q\n", strings.FieldsFunc("a,,b,c", splitFn))
```

In the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Lp1LsoIxAK

Comment: Thanks @T.Claverie, I feel like this is definitely the idiomatic go way to do this.

Comment: Honestly, it would be easier to find this function if it was named `strings.SplitFunc`. Glad it helped you :)

Comment: Interesting. Turns out that using `strings.Split` and then iterating over the array and deleting empty tokens is about 30% more performant.

Comment: I reviewed the source for both `strings.Split` and `strings.FieldsFunc` and found that `FieldsFunc` was doing an extra iteration and so I tested both. `FieldsFunc`'s advantage remains though in that a more complex function can be used for splitting.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out empty elements from an array, so you could do this as a second step.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func delete_empty (s []string) []string {
    var r []string
    for _, str := range s {
        if str != "" {
            r = append(r, str)
        }
    }
    return r
}

func main() {
    var arr = strings.Split("a,,b,c", ",");
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", delete_empty(arr));
}
```

Updated [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/E3zMXK9wNY).

Comment: One may also pre-allocate the `r` since you know the max potential size from the `s`.

Comment: If you pre-allocate it to the length of `s`, you will over-allocate in cases where there are empty fields to skip.

Comment: @Adrian one must assess whether few N-M ~bytes~ runes "lost" is better than extra M allocations.

Comment: I'm concerned about the efficiency of this as I would be calling the code a lot. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Niko when concerned - measure.

Comment: I'm not claiming to have the most graceful answer. Choose the one that you believe is _most readable_. If you find there is a performance problem with whichever code is most readable, it will be easier to optimise. "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." - Knuth

Comment: @Fenton Interesting. Turns out that using your algorithm was about 30% more performant than the `strings.SplitFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

If using `regexp` is acceptable, you could split on 1+ separators:

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("%q\n", regexp.MustCompile(",+").Split("a,,b,c", -1))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/fs04oJkQ_6)

Answer (score 1):

Go 1.21 `slices` package has a `DeleteFunc` function that you can use to delete empty items from a slice.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    items := slices.DeleteFunc(strings.Split("a,,b,c", ","), func(e string) bool {
        return e == ""
    })
    fmt.Println(items)

}
```

output:

```
[a b c]
```